# Matlab imshow doesn't plot correctly but imshowpair does

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, imshow

I have imported an image. I have parsed it to double precision and performed some filtering on it.

When I plot the result with `imshow`, the double image is too dark. But when I use `imshowpair` to plot the original and the final image, both images are correctly displayed.

I have tried to use `uint8`, `im2uint8`, multiply by 255 and then use those functions, but the only way to obtain the correct image is using `imshowpair`.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you try `imshow(im,[]);`?  Also, please show us the code you wrote to parse the image data.  It's impossible to know what's going on without seeing what you tried.

Comment: In order to parse the data I just used  I = im2double(I);   Also, I tried what you said and it worked! Why? And what can I do if I want to store the image in a matrix? Thank you!

Comment: The image is already stored as a matrix, so that doesn't make sense. However, using `im2double` simply converts the image to `double` and if the image is already `double`, nothing happens. It's probably because of the way you are filtering the images.  Are you doing some sort of edge detection?  The reason why you're getting dark images is probably because the majority of your intensities are negative.  `imshow` assumes that for `double` types, the dynamic range of intensities is `[0,1]`, and so doing `imshow(im,[])` shifts the range so the smallest value is mapped to 0, and the largest to 1.

Comment: I was asking how to change the dynamic range of the image, but after your explanation I was able to do it on my own. You don't know how much time I spent trying to solve this issue, and I have finally done it thanks to you! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like a problem where the majority of your intensities / colour data are outside the dynamic range of what is accepted for `imshow` when showing `double` data.

I also see that you're using `im2double`, but `im2double` simply converts the image to double and if the image is already double, nothing happens. It's probably because of the way you are filtering the images. Are you doing some sort of edge detection? The reason why you're getting dark images is probably because the majority of your intensities are negative, or are hovering around 0. `imshow` whe displaying `double` type images assumes that the dynamic range of intensities is [0,1].

Therefore, one way to resolve your problem is to do:

```
imshow(im,[]);
```

This shifts the display so that range so the smallest value is mapped to 0, and the largest to 1.

If you'd like a more permanent solution, consider creating a new output variable that does this for you:

```
out = (im - min(im(:))) / (max(im(:)) - min(im(:)));
```

This will perform the same shifting that `imshow` does when displaying data for you.  You can now just do:

```
imshow(out);
```